# Unable to create the tower as expected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a JavaScript code to build a tower like this:

```
// For nFloors = 3 floors
[
  '  *  ', 
  ' *** ', 
  '*****'
]

// For nFloors = 6 floors, etc...
[
  '     *     ', 
  '    ***    ', 
  '   *****   ', 
  '  *******  ', 
  ' ********* ', 
  '***********'
]
```

I know I have to start from the bottom and continue the logic. Right now I have got till this:

```
function towerBuilder(nFloors) {
  var finalArray = [];
  for (var i = nFloors - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var spaces = nFloors - i;
    var stars = i;
    finalArray.push(" ".repeat(spaces) + "*".repeat(stars));
  }
  return finalArray.reverse();
}
```

I am able to get only the half of it. For e.g., a value of nFloors = 3, gives me this result.

```
[
  "   ",
  "  *",
  " **"
]
```

I know that I am missing something, as I am not able to get the right side part as well. Little confusing on this logic. Can someone help?

Comment: If you really want to learn javascript, try to do exercises by yourself. If you don't know how to, just lower the difficulty level.

Comment: @K.Daniek I think the OP is doing exercises and for a beginner, it looks like a real effort. What do you think? Don't discourage them...

Comment: Some further ways of doing the same thing — always find it good to learn from multiple examples :) https://jsfiddle.net/h6mwf9b4/

Comment: @Pebbl Nice one. I guess many don't understand the question and where it's coming from. Try checking [CodeWars](http://codewars.com)...

Answer (score 3):

Your increment `space` and `stars` counts are contradicting at this point:

```
finalArray.push(" ".repeat(spaces) + "*".repeat(stars));
```

You need to change it, by adding the `spaces` at the right side as well. In your case, you need to finish it before `0`.

```
for (var i = nFloors - 1; i > 0; i--) {
```

I tried solving your snippet this way:

```js
function towerBuilder(nFloors) {
  var finalArray = [];
  var numSpaces = 0;
  // Start from the reverse.
  for (i = nFloors; i > 0; i--) {
    // At the end, the number of spaces are 0.
    // Have one and less for the half of the stars.
    // Add another set of spaces.
    finalArray.push(" ".repeat(numSpaces) + "*".repeat(i) + "*".repeat(i-1)  + " ".repeat(numSpaces));
    // Increment the space, while going to top.
    numSpaces++;
  }
  // Reverse the array.
  return finalArray.reverse();
}
console.log(towerBuilder(3));
```

I would take it in a different way, and this is how I solved a similar problem. So your final snippet should be like:

```js
function towerBuilder(nFloors) {
  var space = "";
  var star = "";
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= nFloors; i++) {
    space = (" ").repeat(nFloors - i);
    star = ("*").repeat((2 * i) - 1);
    result.push(space + star + space);
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(towerBuilder(3));
```

Comment: A little hint or feedback would be far enough to make him do this exercise by himself, instead of giving him a whole working solution. It's rather harming than helping :<

Comment: @K.Daniek but this site is not for hints. Anyone coming to this post expects an answer, not a hint. I believe a section of SO should be dedicated to that, if anything.

Comment: @K.Daniek OKay, I will add some comments.

Comment: @alldani Actually there's an option on codewars, that if you don't know how to make some exercise at all, you can just click and display the answer, but you will loose ability to earn points irrevocably. So... it's kinda cheating :P

Comment: @alldani I have also added comments. Gave the OP two solutions, one with their own way and one with my own way. Not sure if the OP will come back! LoL.

Comment: @K.Daniek Is it okay? How is the answer?

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Got my solution accepted. Thank you very much.

Comment: @K.Daniek not sure if you had more questions for me. Ping me if you do.

Comment: @alldani Mmm, don't think so. Good night!

Comment: I have another question. Can you help me?

Comment: @CodeWarsHelp Yea, go for it. Shoot it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have posted it... Kindly check and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function towerBuilder(nFloors) {
  let array = [];
  for (let i = nFloors; i >= 1; i--) {
    let space = (nFloors - i);
    let stars = i * 2 - 1;
    array.push(" ".repeat(space) + "*".repeat(stars) + " ".repeat(space));
  }
  return array.reverse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the basic programming logic is like this:

```js
function pyramidStar(n) {
  var str = "";

  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= n - i; j++)
      str += ". .";
    for (j = 1; j <= 2 * i - 1; j++)
      str += " *";
    str += "<br />";
  }

  return str;
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = pyramidStar(9);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

I have used '.' instead of space because in html multiple spaces are treated as single space.

Comment: CodeWars doesn't accept anything deviated with a space too. Have you checked it? All the parameters like function signature and return type counts. Did you see the return value?

Answer (score 0):

In this problem you have to care about number of spaces and stars
in each floor. As you can see at each floor number of star = `(floor number) * 2 - 1`. E.g. for floor 2 - number of star will be = `(2 * 2 -1) = 3` such as floor 3 =`(3*2 -1) = 5`. For spaces it is equal to
`nFloor(total number of floor)` - current floor. So for `nFloor = 3` and
`current floor = 1`. Number of spaces = `3 - 1 = 2` on each side of
stars. Similarly for current floor 2 = `3 - 2 = 1`. Thus putting this
logic in codes

```
    function towerBuilder(nFloors) {
      let a = []; //for storing final number of stars and spaces
      let temp = ''; //storing stars and spaces during inner iteration

      //iterating through each floor

      for(let i=0;i<nFloors; i++)
      {

      //storing spaces on left side of the stars.                           
     //Using i+1 because loop is starting from index 0.
        for(let s=0;s<(nFloors-(i+1));s++)
        temp = temp + ' ';

      //storing stars.Using i+1 because loop is starting from index 0.
        for(let j=0;j<(i+1)*2-1;j++)
            temp = temp + '*'

      //for storing stars on the right side of the stars.                   
     //Using i+1 because loop is starting from index 0.
        for(let s=0;s<(nFloors-(i+1)) ;s++)
        temp = temp + ' ';

      //storing tower at each floors  
        a.push(temp)

      //setting temp to null for fresh start for next floor  
        temp = '';

      }
    //returning final tower
      return a;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a solution in php. please note.
if you did not want to add comma (,) on each line of the results then remove

```
$comma = ($i >= $floors) ? "":",";
```

and

```
$result .= $comma;
```

The solution is as follows,

```
<?php
function nfloors(int $floors){
  
  $result = [];
  
  for($i = 1; $i <= $floors; $i++){
    array_push($result,addFloos($floors,$i));

 }
  
  return $result;
}


function addFloos($floors,$i){
  
  $comma = ($i >= $floors) ? "":",";
  
  $result ="";
  
  $result .= addStartMargin($floors,$i);
  $result .= addBrick($i);
  $result .= addEndMargin($floors,$i);
  $result .= $comma;
  
  return $result;
 
}

function addBrick($i){
  $val =  ($i * 2) - 1;
  return str_repeat("*",$val);
}

function addStartMargin($floors,$i){
  $val = ($floors - $i);
  
  return "'".str_repeat(" ",$val);
  
}

function addEndMargin($floors,$i){
  $val = ($floors - $i);
  
  return str_repeat(" ",$val)."'";
  
}

print_r(nfloors(6));
?>
```

This solution also answers the Algorithm question posted on https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/coding-challenge-task-complete-class-tower-takes-positive-integer-parameter-returns-array--q87649158

however there's a slight changes in the pre-written code in the above link, especially in the for loop.